# Ask Ubuntu definition

Tags: discussion, support

Is there any way that this site would/could use the possibility of defining that it is strictly Official Ubuntu and Canonical supported offshoots of Ubuntu?

I had originally thought that this site would be all things Ubuntu, officially supported and not. However, with [my most recent experience (Has since been edited to officially fall within the scope of this site)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/327905/disk-space-and-mounted-network-share), this is not the place for questions of Ubuntu-derived distributions of Linux. I understand that there is Unix/Linux but when I have to defend my system of choice and asking questions when I know it has to deal with the Ubuntu interworkings just turns me off of the site. I look to askubuntu before I go to Unix&Linux because of how Zorin works. It truly is Ubuntu with a closed source, re-compiled version of the Gnome-desktop so that it looks like Windows.

Answer (score 9):

To me the help sections is pretty clear. See https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Copied from there:

> We welcome questions about:
>
> - Using and administering Ubuntu, including [official Ubuntu derivatives](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/derivatives).
> - Running third-party applications on Ubuntu.
> - Development on Ubuntu.
> - Services provided by Ubuntu
> - Any question not mentioned below or here are great! There are no "dumb" questions!
>
> This is not the right place for:
>
> - Linux Mint, Backtrack, Gnome-Remix (prior to 13.04) and other Linux distributions (try our friends at Unix & Linux Stack Exchange).
> - Bug reports (How do I submit a bug?).
> - Issues with the next version of Ubuntu (Ubuntu+1) (More information about Alpha and Beta release issues).
> - Shopping Recommendations
> - Support of versions for Ubuntu releases past "End of Life" (EOL)

---

From the link:

**Recognised Ubuntu flavours**

These are derivatives that use Ubuntu as their foundation and contribute significantly towards the project.

- Edubuntu — Ubuntu for education
- Ubuntu GNOME — Ubuntu with the GNOME desktop environment
- Kubuntu — Ubuntu with the K Desktop environment
- UbuntuKylin — Ubuntu localised for China
- Lubuntu — Ubuntu that uses LXDE
- Mythbuntu — Designed for creating a home theatre PC with MythTV
- Ubuntu Studio — Designed for multimedia editing and creation
- Xubuntu — Ubuntu with the XFCE desktop environment

Comment: Okay then how about this, How about we make a feature request that allows for users who's issues are not rectified to click a link that moves the question to unix & linux. Instead of just leaving it closed, they now can get the proper help that fits the scope even if it was an ubuntu-ish issue.

Comment: That is feature you could ask on the SO meta. But from a database point of view I could imagine this to be a lot of work.

Comment: You can still click edit on a closed question you posted, then just copy and paste the post into unix.stackexchange.com to "move" it there.

Comment: @JorgeCastro Considering the number of questions about non-official Ubuntu derivatives or beta releases and even other Linux distribution that AU gets, I'm surprised that [so few](http://askubuntu.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats) get migrated to U&L. I think a migration path would make sense, and in the meantime mods are welcome to migrate such questions (when they would be acceptable for AU if they were about a supported distribution).

Comment: @Gilles I think a migration path makes sense.